# How do I access static 2D vector in a static function?

Tags: c++, static-methods, static-variables

I need a way to access static 2D vector in my static function. The reason being I want to use syntax like **GameBoard::initBoard()** in my **main()** function.Observe the following code snippets. I have higlighted error in comments

GameBoard Header

```
class GameBoard
{
    public:
        static void initBoard();


    protected:

    private:
        static std::vector <std::vector<char>> chessBoard;
};
```

InitBoard implementation is as follows

```
void GameBoard::initBoard()
{
    std::vector<char> blankPos {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'};
    for(int i{0}; i < 8; i++)
    {
        chessBoard.push_back(blankPos);       //getting Error here
    }

}
```

The error shown is:

> undefined reference to `GameBoard::chessBoard'

Comment: In the class you only *declare* the static member variable `chessBoard`, you need to *define* it as well. Any decent [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), class or tutorial should have an explanation about this. As would millions of examples all over the greater Internet, of which many thousands of them would be here on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thanks for the info!! that worked like  a charm!!